# Get state of the command on application launch

Tags: java, eclipse, command, toggle, state

in my eclipse application I need to add listeners if certain toggle menu is activated. I add them in the execute method of my command. I want this state to be persistant, so I use RegistryToggleState. Now I have a problem, that if the state is enabled on the launch of the application the menu which is linked to my command could never be clicked. In this case my listeners won't be added.
I thought I could let my plugin start early and simply run HandlerUTils.togglecommandState twice.Otherwise I would need to get the state of teh command on start so that I can add the listeners myself if the command is enabled . But for both I need to get the command by id on early startup. I tried to do it with the following:

```
@Override
    public void earlyStartup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.err.println("plugin started");
        ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) PlatformUI
                .getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getService(
                ICommandService.class);
                Command command = commandService
                .getCommand("jeff.synchronization.commands.synchronizeClients");
                try {
                    HandlerUtil.toggleCommandState(command);
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("state toggled");
    }
```

But now I get an Exception because the ActiveWorkbenchWindow cannot be found on early startup. Is there any way to get a command by id on start? My worst case solution would be to always set the state on false by start so that user has to set the flag himself.

```
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jeff.synchronization.Activator.earlyStartup(Activator.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2555)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
18145    [Worker-5] ERROR org.eclipse.logger  - PLUGIN=jeff.synchronization: Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jeff.synchronization.Activator.earlyStartup(Activator.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2555)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
2027890  [main] INFO  jeff.database.jpa.core.factory.EclipseLinkLogAdapter  - logout_successful
```

Comment: What is `Activator.java:89` line?

Comment: Early startup runs before the workbench window is initialized

Comment: Sorry, it helped to simply ask the question. The problem was that the activeWorkbenchWindow could not be got. Now I get the service directly from the workbench with ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) PlatformUI
                .getWorkbench().getService(
                ICommandService.class);

Comment: Sorry for bothering you